# Unable to create directory uploads/2018/12. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Tags: uploads

Few days ago I migrated my site to a new server and the problem started after that, before migrating everything was fine. Now, when I click on add media and select any image it says... Unable to create directory uploads/2018/12. Is its parent directory writable by the server? I found some answers to this question, and have tried to edit the options.php file but no luck yet also I have checked it and fourd that the permissions on above directory is 777. So please check the same and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the common issue we are facing when we change the server of the website.However in this there is no issue of permission to folder .
In your admin, go to Settings/Media and change the upload path to that of the new server.

[image: Check the path here]